# Downloading a File From Virtual Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, download, virtual-directory, iis-8

I am doing something wrong here, but not able to figure it out. I have a virtual directory and a files inside it and I want to download the file.

My code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    string FileName = Request.Params["IMS_FILE_NAME"];
    string FullFileLogicalPath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VIRTUAL_DIR_PATH"], FileName);
    string FullfilePhysicalPath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PHYSICAL_DIR_PATH"], FileName);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullfilePhysicalPath))
    {
        return File( FullFileLogicalPath , "Application/pdf", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { Success = "false" });
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> http:/localhost/Images/PDF/150763-3.pdf is not a valid virtual path.

If I post this URL `http:/localhost/Images/PDF/150763-3.pdf` in my browser, the file is opened. How can I download this file?

Platform MVC 4, IIS 8.

Comment: On which line of your code are you getting this error?

Comment: getting error in Global.asax in method Application_Error()

Comment: With IIS 7.5 works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `http://localhost/Images/PDF/150763-3.pdf` (instead of http:/)

Chrome will change http:/ to http:// but your program will not.

---

I think I misread your question.

Try (fixed from comment)

```
return File(FullfilePhysicalPath, "Application/pdf", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()+".pdf");
```

Comment: If I debugg my code and put mouse over FullFileLogicalPath ( in side if condition )  it is showing me "http:\\\\localhost\\Images\\PDF\\150763-3.pdf" and if i click on the Button of tooltip , inside Text Visualizer it is showing me http:\\localhost\Images\PDF\150763-3.pdf so where is the problem ? where i am missing the "/" ?

Comment: i tried your solution of appending ".pdf" at end, but still its not working, in Global.asax Application_Error() Method i am getting an exception 'http:/localhost/Images/PDF/150771-1.pdf' is not a valid virtual path.  i am not getting how come http:// converted in to http:/ ?

Comment: Why aren't you using the FullfilePhysicalPath?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use routes url in format: "{controller}/{action}/{id}":

There is class RouteConfig  defined ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs in MVC 4
You have ImageController and PDF action and 150763-3.pdf is the parameter id.

[http://localhost/Images/PDF/150763-3.pdf](http://150763-3.pdf)

Solution is very simple:

```
public class ImagesController : Controller
    {
        [ActionName("PDF")]
        public ActionResult DownloadFile(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpNotFoundResult();

            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            string FileName = id;

            string FullFileLogicalPath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VIRTUAL_DIR_PATH"], FileName);
            string FullfilePhysicalPath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PHYSICAL_DIR_PATH"], FileName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullfilePhysicalPath))
            {
                return File(FullFileLogicalPath, "Application/pdf", FileName);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Success = "false" });
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: I did the same(put [ActionName("PDF")] just above my action ), still it is showing me same error "http:/localhost/Images/PDF/150763-3.pdf is not a valid virtual path."

Comment: It's curious. My code works fine. ... Which line throws exception?